# Sum 1 column based from date selection in Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to figure out a way to do this sum in one line, or without having to create another dataframe in memory.

I have a DF with 3 columns. ['DateCreated', 'InvoiceNumber', 'InvoiceAmount']

I am trying to SUM the invoice amount during certain date ranges.

I have this working, but I want to do it without having to create a DF then sum the column. Any help is appreciated.

```
        yesterday_sales_df = df[(df['DateCreated'] > yesterday_date) & (df['DateCreated'] < tomorrow_date)]
        yesterday_sales_total = yesterday_sales_df['InvoiceAmount'].sum()
        print(yesterday_sales_total)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try with `loc`

```py
yesterday_sales_total = df.loc[(df['DateCreated'] > yesterday_date) & (df['DateCreated'] < tomorrow_date), 'InvoiceAmount'].sum()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this as well

```
# filter df with query
yesterday_sales_total = df.query("@yesterday_date < DateCreated < @tomorrow_date")['InvoiceAmount'].sum()
```

Answer (score 1):

try `between`:

```
sales_total = df[df['DateCreated'].between(yesterday_date, tomorrow_date)]['InvoiceAmount'].sum()
```

if it's nessesary set `inclusive` argument (inclusive='both' by default)